# In Visual Studio (2017) is it possible to view all local variables in scope while editing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Autos and Locals windows are available only while debugging. I wonder if there's a way to see all variable declarations in the method under cursor.

Comment: What exactly do you want "under cursor"? If you want to speed up coding, then Intellisense clearly shows all variable declarations.

Comment: They show up in the IntelliSense auto-completion suggest box.  But without the option to limit the list to only local variables.  It in no way encourages anybody to write methods so large that this feature is useful or necessary.